# Other approach to find $f(x)$ when $f(x+y)=2^xf(y)+4^yf(x)$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

> Consider a differentiable function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ for which $f(1)=2$ and $f(x+y)=2^xf(y)+4^yf(x)\;\forall\;x,y\in\mathbb R$, find the minimum value of $f(x)$.

One approach is to replace $x$ and $y$, subtract the two equations, use the initial condition and obtain $f(x)=4^x-2^x$. Taking derivative or completing the whole square, we can get the minimum value.

But I wonder if there is any other approach to solve it. Maybe taking derivative of the initial equation keeping one variable as constant or maybe using the first principle. e.g. $$f'(x)=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{f(x+y)-f(x)}{y}\\=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{2^xf(y)+f(x)(4^y-1)}{y}$$

Can we finish this apporach?

Comment: $$f'(x)=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{f(x+y)-f(x)}{y}\\$$
$$=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{2^xf(y)+f(x)(4^y-1)}{y}=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{2^xf(y)}{y}+\lim_{y\to0}\frac{f(x)(4^y-1)}{y}$$
$$f'(x)=2^xf'(0)+f(x).ln(4)$$

Comment: @ShivamM Thanks. $$\frac{dy}{dx}-(\ln4)y=2^xf'(o)$$ So, IF$=e^{-\int\ln4dx}=4^{-x}$. $$y\cdot4^{-x}=\int2^{-x}f'(0)dx+c\\\implies4^{-x}y=-f'(0)\ln2\cdot2^{-x}+c$$ Using initial condition, we can calculate $c$ but can we calculate $f'(0)$ as well?

Comment: To calculate $f'(0)$ (so explicitly $f$) it might be helpful to plug in the formula for $f$ (which involves $f'(0)$, the one u calculated above by integrals) into the equation $f(x+y) = 4^yf(x) + 2^xf(y)$ and solve for $f'(0)$.

Comment: @DominikKutek thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments. $$f'(x)=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{f(x+y)-f(x)}{y}\\=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{2^xf(y)+f(x)(4^y-1)}{y}\\=2^xf'(0)+f(x)\ln4$$

It's a first order linear differential equation.

$$\frac{dy}{dx}-(\ln4)y=2^xf'(o)$$ So, IF$=e^{-\int\ln4dx}=4^{-x}$. $$y\cdot4^{-x}=\int2^{-x}f'(0)dx+c\\\implies4^{-x}y=-\frac{f'(0)}{\ln2}\cdot2^{-x}+c$$

Calculating $c$ using initial condition, thus, $$f(x)=-2^x\frac{f'(0)}{\ln2}+2^{2x-1}\left(1+\frac{f'(0)}{\ln2}\right)$$

Plugging this back in the given equation, I get $$f'(0)=\ln2$$

Thus, $$f(x)=4^x-2^x$$